# using CSS properties

Tags: css, html

I started coding html website with `CSS` and `<div>'s`. Before, I would (en)code with tables. I have to ask this question because I don't know how can I code properly with `CSS` and `<div>s.`

I tried something but I found a lot of bugs and I asked all of them by this site. 
Now, for ex.: What is the different between the 'margin-top' and 'top' properties or 'margin' and 'top, left, right, bottom' properties.

I want to learn something like that. I know `CSS` so so but I want to learn properties of `<div>` tag.
Please help me,
Thanks a lot.

Edit: Not only margin or 'top, left, right, bottom' properties. I want to learn all of `<div>` tag properties and `<div>` tag positioning `CSS`s (properties). I need a lot of idea and document. Please write what do you know. :)

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest learning about the box model:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

And reference the W3C site for the DIV tag:

http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/div

And maybe read about CSS Reset scripts:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/04/18/reset-reasoning/

Answer (score 1):

If you set `margin:5px` will add `margin` for all sides of the element (top,right,bottom,left). If you want to specify the side of the margin, for example top, you can you use `margin-top:5px`. But also, you can use

`margin:5px 10px 15px 20px` this is a shorthand of the following properties

```
margin-top:5px;
margin-right:10px;
margin-bottom:15px;
margin-left:20px;
```

The same philosophy is used for `padding`.

An easy to follow guide for css is the following: http://www.cssbasics.com/

The css 2.1 recommendations can be found here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/

Using [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or any built-in developer tools, it's great help to understand how css works and play easily with it.

Also, sitepoint has good css reference: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css

Answer (score 0):

`top` moves an element in various different ways, depending on the value of [the `position` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#positioning-scheme).

`margin-top` puts a space between the top of the element and the previous element (subject to the rules for [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins))